# How to remove a trailing comma?

Tags: ruby, regex

Given strings like:

```
Bob
Bob,
Bob
Bob Burns,
```

How can you return that w/o a comma?

```
Bob
Bob
Bob
Bob Burns
```

Also, I would want this method not to break if passed a nil, just to return a nil?

```
def remove_trailing_comma(str)
  !str.nil? ? str.replace(",") :nil
end
```

Comment: The code you supplied wouldn't work, because you don't have quotation marks around the comma, and it's `!str.nil? ?` not `!str.nil ?`. Please use IRB to check your code next time.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

My thought would be to use [string.chomp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001188):

> Returns a new String with the given record separator removed from the end of str (if present).

Does this do what you want?

```
def remove_trailing_comma(str)
    str.nil? ? nil : str.chomp(",")
end
```

Comment: It is more elegant to write it as `str.chomp(',') if (str)`.

Comment: Or `str&.chomp(',')` if you're using Ruby 2.3+.

Answer (score 6):

use [String#chomp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001188)

```
irb(main):005:0> "Bob".chomp(",")
=> "Bob"
irb(main):006:0> "Bob,".chomp(",")
=> "Bob"
irb(main):007:0> "Bob Burns,".chomp(",")
=> "Bob Burns"
```

UPDATE:

```
def awesome_chomp(str)
    str.is_a?(String) ? str.chomp(",") : nil
end
p awesome_chomp "asd," #=> "asd"
p awesome_chomp nil #=> nil
p awesome_chomp Object.new #=> nil
```

Comment: What about dealing with nils? private method `chomp' called for nil:NilClass):

Comment: Any reason to prefer `str.is_a?(String)` to something like `str.respond_to?(:chomp)` ?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
str && str.sub(/,$/, '')
```

Comment: Thanks good but nils break that "private method `sub' called for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Yeah I realized that and updated the code. It should work now. In fact the chomp method is probably better:
str && str.chomp(",")

Answer (score 1):

As everyone said, `chomp` will do the trick.
Starting from Ruby 2.3 you can use the **safe navigation operator** like this: `str&.chomp(',')`. It will only execute chomp if str is not nil, otherwise it will return nil.

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
str.delete_suffix(',')
```